# How to use variable from generate method to another method

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured, gherkin

In short when i run this commend  `mvn clean test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@Test1"` after i run   `mvn clean test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@Test2"` command i want i can use the variable created in the previous method in the other method. For example;

```
@Test1
Scenario: Create Folder
    When I create folder with "test" name api
```

This scenerio linked this method

```
@When("^I create folder with \"([^\"]*)\" name api$")
public void createFolder(String name) {

    response = RestAssured.given()
            .baseUri(prp_url)
            .accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .header("X-Auth-Token", xAuthToken.userAuth())
            .header("Folder-Name", name)
            .header("Folder-Uuid", "123456")
            .queryParam("parentFolderUuid", "")
            .when()
            .post("/filesystem/createFolder")
            .then().extract().response();

    getUuid = getJsonPath(response, "uuid");    
}
```

And here is my second scenerio

````
@Test2
Scenario: Create inside the Folder
    When I send create inside the folder with "1" name api
```

And this scenerio is also linked this method
```
@When("^I send create inside the folder with \"([^\"]*)\" name api$")
public void createInsideFolder(String name) {

    String uuid = getUuid();

    response = RestAssured.given()
            .baseUri(prp_url)
            .accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .header("X-Auth-Token", xAuthToken.userAuth())
            .header("Folder-Name", name)
            .header("Folder-Uuid", "123456")
            .queryParam("parentFolderUuid", getUuid)
            .when()
            .post("/filesystem/createFolder")
            .then()
            .extract().response();
}
```
So when I use the same tag, I can use the variable created in the previous method in the other method, but when I run each scenario with different tags, I get a null pointer error. How can I run 2 scenarios separately and use the variable in the previous method in the other method?
````

Comment: Did I answer your question? It would be nice getting feedback from you.

Comment: Oh thank you for your advice . I tried background options and that is awesome idea for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Can*** you do this? Yes, you can.

***Should*** you do this? Absolutely not! Unless, you are creating a *Background* to do this.

Under no circumstance, you should create a scenario that depends on another scenario. Scenarios are meant to be run independently and in no specific order. Creating a dependency such as the one you described here is counterproductive. But, against my better judgment, I am going to show you how to do it...

*Create a global variable!*

```
public class MyFeatureClass {

    private String folderName = "";

    @When("^I create folder with \"([^\"]*)\" name api$")
    public void createFolder(String name) {

        response = RestAssured.given()
            .baseUri(prp_url)
            .accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .header("X-Auth-Token", xAuthToken.userAuth())
            .header("Folder-Name", name)
            .header("Folder-Uuid", "123456")
            .queryParam("parentFolderUuid", "")
            .when()
            .post("/filesystem/createFolder")
            .then().extract().response();

        getUuid = getJsonPath(response, "uuid");
        folderName = // whatever;
    }

    @When("^I send create inside the folder with \"([^\"]*)\" name api$")
    public void createInsideFolder(String name) {

        // Use "folderName" here
        String uuid = getUuid();

        response = RestAssured.given()
            .baseUri(prp_url)
            .accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .header("X-Auth-Token", xAuthToken.userAuth())
            .header("Folder-Name", name)
            .header("Folder-Uuid", "123456")
            .queryParam("parentFolderUuid", getUuid)
            .when()
            .post("/filesystem/createFolder")
            .then()
            .extract().response();
    }
}
```

A better approach is to use a `Background`. A background in Cucumber is very much the same as what `@Before` annotation is for JUnit or TestNG. A background step definition is a chunk of code that runs automatically before each scenario (whether a particular scenario needs it or not). This is the correct place to resolve all the dependencies a scenario might need to execute correctly. In the cucumber file, add a background after the declaration of the feature, like this:

```
Feature: Test Background Feature
Description: The purpose of this feature is to test the Background keyword

Background: Files and Folders are created
    When I create folder with "XYZ" name api

Scenario: Create subfolder
    Given Open my app
    When I send create inside the folder with "1" name api
    Then I can create files inside folder
```

To access this variable, do the same as I proposed: declare it as global. When you add scenarios to this feature that require this attribute, they will be able to access it automatically.

If you are required to use a variable in between steps, you should be able to use the same strategy.

Comment: This won't work. If you want to share a state between steps you have to apply DI framework integration capabilities of Cucumber. Probably approach with static variables will work but it is highly discouraged due to instable behavior in multithreded case.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I would concede that it might not be the best approach, but to say it won't work is simply not true. I have done this many times. A Cucumber step is linked to a Java method. Java methods have access to global variables in the class. This is not rocket science.

Comment: Alright, true. You're right. Took my downvote back. When you have all your step defs in a single class that might work. But won;t work if steps of your scenario are spread amon different classes.